# Bootstrap Migrating or Updating Between v3.X

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, migrate

Is there is a guide to migrate or update between v3.X

For example migrate from v3.1.0 to v3.2.0

Is it safe to update without making any changes?

Comment: Yes, read the release notes.

Comment: Release notes give some changes, but does not give a guide to how to upgrade

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Bootstrap adheres to Semantic Versioning](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap#versioning), so there should be no incompatibilities when upgrading within the v3 release series. No changes should be necessary unless you want to use the new features added in 3.2.

The only conscious derogation from SemVer within v3 so far has been a change in v3.1.0 to the markup expected for `remote` modals. And remote modals are being deprecated in v3.2.1 anyway.

Comment: I have used different colors in my bootstrap how can I easily upgrade bootstrap 3.0 to 3.2 keeping my colors ?