# What are the major migration issues between Bootstrap 3.0.3 and 3.2.0?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

We've inherited a Bootstrap dashboard that is in BS 3.0.3, and we'd like to be using 3.2.0, but not if it is going to create a lot of development time to migrate it.  I was just curious if anyone had some guidance with regards to migration, it's a pretty complex dashboard.

Comment: 3.0.3 > 3.2.0 is not a migration--it's a one-click update. All extensions and templates built by reputable developers should be compatible, though they should be updated first.

Comment: Twitter Bootstrap follows Semantic Versioning (more here: http://semver.org/), meaning that minor releases are backward compatible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and link, I'd never heard of Semantic Versioning.  Also, thanks to whoever down voted my not knowing about Semantic Versioning and how Bootstrap adheres to it.

Comment: Probably because that information is in the docs

Comment: Are there docs outside of these: http://getbootstrap.com/? Semantic occurs once in these docs and it isn't a reference to Semantic Versioning.

Comment: @mtpultz It's covered in the README: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap#versioning

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bootstrap Migrating or Updating Between v3.X](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25111312/bootstrap-migrating-or-updating-between-v3-x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full release notes for 3.2.0 are located here: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases/tag/v3.2.0

Maybe you have inherited one of the Start Bootstrap dashboards?

If so you'll find further info here: http://startbootstrap.com/template-categories/admin-dashboard/